# Material input type datetime-local shows its own placeholder and toggle button

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I'm trying to render the angular material date picker. Which is not the problem ([DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-example-xutjba?file=app%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.html))

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input
        matInput
       [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"
       [matDatepicker]="picker"
       placeholder="Choose a date"
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But in my case I need a date-time picker. From what I found on the web, you simple add

```
 type="datetime-local"
```

to the input field. And I can confirm that this works, but it does weird things with the input field.

[image]

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-example-dhayys?file=app%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.html)

Although angular material seems to support [this type](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) the picker you get however is native.

It has its own toggle button and it shows default text `dd/mm/yyyy --:--`. Is there a way to hide this text and toggle button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular material does not support time picker currently, but there is an open issue requesting that: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5648

You can try to use 3rd party extension for date & time picker until it is added to Angular material: https://ng-matero.github.io/extensions/components/datetimepicker/overview

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find time-picker feature in Angular Material.

Try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/datetime-picker

[image: date-time-picker]

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the toggle line and the [matDatepicker] directive:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
    required
    formControlName = "start"
    type="datetime-local"
    placeholder="Data Lezione"
    >
    <mat-datepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is working for me and frankly speaking I don't understand how the input and the datepicker are connected with each other: possibly just because they're inside the same mat-form-field. But it works!
The only issue is that you can't disable specific days or times as you don't have a reference to the toggle in the input, so the [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" is not working...